# I'm not able to control the height of an iframe

Tags: iframe, blazor

In my Blazor application I'm trying to display swagger within the application instead of navigating to swagger.  Here's the code I'm trying to use.

```
@page "/admin/swagger"
@*@attribute [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]*@
@*@attribute [Authorize]*@

<iframe src="swagger" height="400px"></iframe>
```

It's rendering like this...

[image]

How do I get it to have a static height or at least fill the page?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `CSS` isolation on your page to do the sizing.

AdminSwagger.razor

```
@page "/admin/swagger"

<iframe src="swagger"></iframe>
```

AdminSwagger.razor.css - file within the same folder that contains your component `AdminSwagger.razor`

```
iframe {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
}
```

You will need to adjust the `CSS` to fit your application's UI.