# How would I get height in an iframe within a razor page to adjust?

Tags: blazor

Here's my code.

```
<MudItem xs="6">
  <p>URL: 
    @if (piece.ClipUrl == "")
    {
      <span class="badge bg-warning">no clip url</span>
    }
    else
    {
      <a href=@piece.ClipUrl>@piece.ClipUrl</a>
    }
    </p>
    <p><iframe width="560"
               height="400"
               style="border:1px solid black;"
               src=@ClipUrlSrc
               frameborder="1"
               allowfullscreen></iframe></p>
    </MudItem>
```

When I render this in Razor the height is not being used. I can change the height of the iframe to 800 and rerun the app and the iframe doesn't change.

What can I do to get this working?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try specifying pixels on your dimensions? i.e. `width="560px"` and `height="400px"`. Sometimes browsers do weird things when you don't specify the units.

Comment: I just tried that and still not correct, but thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Put the height and width in the style attribute in pixels.

Comment: You asked the same question here? [I'm not able to control the height of an iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73855220/im-not-able-to-control-the-height-of-an-iframe)